# How to access webcam in Godot on non-Apple platforms?

Tags: camera, godot

When I search for how to access the webcam in Godot, I find the [CameraServer](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.6/classes/class_cameraserver.html), but the docs say:

> **Note:** This class is currently only implemented on macOS and iOS. On other platforms, no [CameraFeeds](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.6/classes/class_camerafeed.html#class-camerafeed) will be available.

But I do now have any Apple devices to test with. Is there a way I can access the webcam on non-Apple devices, or in a cross-platform way?

Answer (score 3):

There's at least one plugin providing some [Android](https://github.com/Lamelynx/GodotGetImagePlugin-Android) support. There are pull requests for both [Windows](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/pull/49763) and [Linux](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/pull/47967) support.